I have to perform a calculation across multiple measures spread across crosstabs
I am trying to calculate a ratio of two measures at a given point of time . One measure is contained in one column whereas the other measure is spread across various columns in the data base with each column representing the value of the measure at a point in time.
I have created a calculated field after pivoting the data
The issue I am facing is that the link between the two crosstabs is not working
Attached below are the two sheets I am using where Sheet 2 contains the columns which were pivoted into a column named Values and my calculated field is Sales*Value.


